# Front screen switching

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a front screen which I am going to put for my project. 
 But the issue is its not happening. It should be like, by pressing some specified key front screen should switch with the project screen.

Here what i have done is, I have specified an integer value to a variable.

```
int flag=0;
```

And I have a key for it, defined as:

```
if(key=='b'||key=='B')
{   
    if(flag==0)
        flag=1;
}
```

Then I'm providing conditions in a function.

```
  void mydisplay(void)
  {
   //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if(flag==0)
        window();
    if(flag==1)
        display();
 }
```

the window function is defined as:

```
 void window(void)
{   
 glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize (1920,1080);
glutInitWindowPosition (0,0);
glutCreateWindow ("3D GLOBE");
glutDisplayFunc (display10);
glutIdleFunc (display10);
glutReshapeFunc (reshape10);

//Load our texture
texture[9] = LoadTexture1( "docd.bmp", 1754, 1240 );
}
```

And after this I am calling the mydisplay function in main function

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{


glutInit (&argc, argv);


glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

glutInitWindowSize (1920,1080);

glutInitWindowPosition (0,0);

glutCreateWindow ("3D GLOBE");

init();

createmenu(); 


glutDisplayFunc (mydisplay);
glutIdleFunc (spinsphere);


glutKeyboardFunc(keys);

glutReshapeFunc (reshape);


glutMainLoop ();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just have:

```
int flag=0;
```

and

```
if(key=='b'||key=='B')
{   
    if(flag==1)
        flag=0;
}
```

That condition is never fullfilled, so the key press will never have any effect, and 'flag` will always stay at 0.

Comment: I have made some changes.      if(key=='b'||key=='B')
{   
    if(flag==0)
        flag=1;
}  but is no use.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is really simple. Just copy the project code functions to the specific key you want assign to enter your project. And the cover page display functions to the main function.

here is the code 
This is my project functions which i am using it in main previously.

```
if(key=='b'||key=='B')
  { 
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (1920,1080);
    glutInitWindowPosition (0,0);
    glutCreateWindow ("3D GLOBE");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    createmenu(); 
    glutIdleFunc (spinsphere);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keys);
    glutReshapeFunc (reshape);
    }
```

and here is my main function
also make sure that you will use keyboard functions on both the places

```
   int main (int argc, char **argv)
   {


     glutInit (&argc, argv);
         //front screen functions
     glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize (1920,1080);
    glutInitWindowPosition (0,0);
     glutCreateWindow ("3D GLOBE");
    glutDisplayFunc (display10);
    glutIdleFunc (display10);
    glutReshapeFunc (reshape10);
    //Load our texture
    texture[9] = LoadTexture1( "docd.bmp", 1754, 1240 );
    glutKeyboardFunc(keys);
   /*glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
   glutInitWindowSize (1920,1080);
   glutInitWindowPosition (0,0);
   glutCreateWindow ("3D GLOBE");
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
  init();   
  createmenu();
  glutIdleFunc (spinsphere);
  glutKeyboardFunc(keys);
  glutReshapeFunc (reshape);

 */ 
   glutMainLoop ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is your indentation so wonky?

Comment: It takes ten seconds to write proper indentation and you should get into the habit of doing it by default, and _definitely_ when posting your code here. Surely it takes _more_ effort to get it wrong?!

Comment: Ok. I'll keep that in mind when I'll be posting in future.